# align two pandas dataframes on values in one column, otherwise insert NA to match row number

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames (`df1`, `df2`) with a different number of rows and columns and some matching values in a specific column in each `df`, with caveats (1) there are some unique values in each `df`, and (2) there are different numbers of matching values across the DataFrames.

Baby example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id2': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'var1': ['B', 'B', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'H', 'B', 'A']})
```

What I am seeking to do is create `df3` where `df2['id2']` is aligned/indexed to `df1['id1']`, such that:

1. `NaN` is added to `df3[id2]` when `df2[id2]` has fewer (or missing) matches to `df1[id1]`
2. `NaN` is added to `df3[id2]` & `df3[var1]` if `df1[id1]` exists but has no match to `df2[id2]`
3. `'var1'` is filled in for all cases of `df3[var1]` where `df1[id1]` and `df2[id2]` match
4. rows are dropped when `df2[id2]` has more matching values than `df1[id1]` (or no matches at all)

The resulting DataFrame (`df3`) should look as follows (Notice id2 = 5 and var1 = A are gone):

| id1 | id2 | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 1 | NaN | B |
| 2 | 2 | W |
| 2 | 2 | W |
| 3 | 3 | H |
| 3 | NaN | H |
| 3 | NaN | H |
| 3 | NaN | H |
| 4 | 4 | B |
| 6 | NaN | NaN |
| 6 | NaN | NaN |

I cannot find a combination of merge/join/concatenate/align that correctly solves this problem. Currently, everything I have tried stacks the rows in sequence without adding `NaN` in the proper cells/rows and instead adds all the `NaN` values at the bottom of `df3` (so `id1` and `id2` never align). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can first assign a helper column for `id1` and `id2` based on `groupby.cumcount`, then merge. Finally `ffill` values of `var1` based on the group `id1`

```
def helper(data,col): return data.groupby(col).cumcount()

out = df1.assign(k = helper(df1,['id1'])).merge(df2.assign(k = helper(df2,['id2'])),
      left_on=['id1','k'],right_on=['id2','k'] ,how='left').drop('k',1)

out['var1'] = out['id1'].map(dict(df2[['id2','var1']].drop_duplicates().to_numpy()))
```

Or similar but without assign as [HenryEcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) suggests :

```
out = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['id1', helper(df1, ['id1'])], 
      right_on=['id2', helper(df2, ['id2'])], how='left').drop(columns='key_1')

out['var1'] = out['id1'].map(dict(df2[['id2','var1']].drop_duplicates().to_numpy()))
```

---

```
print(out)

    id1  id2 var1
0     1  1.0    B
1     1  1.0    B
2     1  NaN    B
3     2  2.0    W
4     2  2.0    W
5     3  3.0    H
6     3  NaN    H
7     3  NaN    H
8     3  NaN    H
9     4  4.0    B
10    6  NaN  NaN
11    6  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Little used trick, but `on` `left_on` and `right_on` can take Series. `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['id1', helper(df1, ['id1'])], right_on=['id2', helper(df2, ['id2'])], how='left').drop(columns='key_1')` Can help prevent making copies of dataframes if they are larger.

Comment: @HenryEcker Many thanks, can I add that in my solution?

Comment: Wow, beautiful and efficient. Works perfectly. Thanks so much. I struggled with this problem and was not versed in the 'helper' technique. A great solution and a big help!

Comment: @user388754 , pleasure. Please consider accepting the answer if it helped.